# SQL Query to select all users without order, name, physical address and phone number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run SQL query in WooCommerce to select all users without order, name, physical address and phone number. I have run the following code, but it's not working for me.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_usermeta m
  JOIN wp_users u
    ON m.user_id = u.ID
 WHERE m.user_id NOT IN 
    ( SELECT um1.user_id 
       FROM wp_usermeta um1 
      WHERE um1.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name'`)
```

This query is not retrieving users without required data. I just want to find spam users form my site and delete those.

Comment: how we know without seeing data of yours table  why not  this query return data and does not returning data not means its not working

Comment: Table is default user table in wordpress

Comment: Firstly, I really don't know the meaning of three tables, can you explain them for me, so I can understand the sql you provided. And in you sql, JOIN is equal to INNER JOIN and means getting datas that both of tables have the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery

```
select * from
(SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta JOIN wp_users ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID)a
WHERE not exists 
(SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta um1 WHERE um1.user_id=a.user_id and
um1.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name')
```